# Can the White King capture the bishop?

Tags: advantage

Here is the satuation
Black: King(b7), rook (a8), Bishop (e8,b4), pawn (c7,e6,f7,g7)
White: King(c4), rook (g4), Knight (f3), pawn (b2,c2,f2,g3)

It is white to move.

```
r3b3/1kp2pp1/4p3/8/1bK3R1/5NP1/1PP2P2/8 w - - 0 1
```

In this case, can the white king (c4) capture the black Bishop (b4)?

Comment: See how to add a diagram to your question here: https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post

Comment: Is the question "is it a legal move?" or "is it a good move?" or ?

Comment: Regardless, white is pretty well doomed. Black has the bishop pair, white is about to lose material, and is already basically trapped. At this point black will almost certainly win, barring a blunder.

Answer (score 11):

A more complete answer:

- Is it legal? Yes, it's a legal king move and the king is not in check afterwards.
- Is it good? No, as after Ra4+ followed by Rxg4 White is a whole rook down instead of a light piece.
- Is it relevant? Hardly, Black simply keeps a large winning advantage (after best move Rxg7) anyway, so you can as well take on b4 and pray to Caissa to strike your opponent with chess blindness :-)

Comment: Hope that black sees rook a4 and doesn't like it?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim hope he is not a psychic either

Answer (score 1):

The problem of course is the Ra4+ and the x-ray attack on the white rook, resulting in its loss, so that would be a bad move.

Depending who you play, you may be able to play white pawn B3. If ignored, then the Ra4+ will either not be played, or will result in the loss the of the black rook as it moves to A4.

Answer (score -1):

The black bishop on b4 is unprotected, so it's free for the taking.

Unfortunately, that's not the best move according to Stockfish.

Comment: Except its not free...

Comment: An explanation of why Stockfish doesn't like the move would have been great!